# Check to see if input exists while reading from txt

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

My program operates on a text file that contains various commands. Out of these, one is "show" which displays an array or an element from the array. The command can have the following two forms:

```
1) show arrayName
2) show arrayName arrayIndex
```

The first command displays the whole array, whereas the second command displays the element of the array at the arrayIndex given (after checking if index exists; gives error otherwise). I have to handle these with ONE input stream. I understand the general idea of how to do this, but can implement only one function at a time i.e. I cannot check beforehand if arrayIndex exists.

For the following line of code,

```
    in >> arrayName >> arrayIndex;
```

I can display the element at the arrayIndex when an integer value is present. However, when an index is not present (whole array has to be displayed), the input stream assigns garbage values to arrayIndex. Is there a way to differentiate between the two commands?

Comment: You probably need to read in your string to the end-of-line character, then parse it yourself instead of depending on C++ stream input operators.

Comment: The input stream does not "assign garbage values".  It fails and leaves `arrayIndex` unchanged (which may have had a garbage value already).

Comment: What do you mean by: "I cannot check if arrayIndex exists before hand"??? How else are you going to make sure the index is within bounds??

Comment: @Brandon The command can either have an index or not. If it doesn't have an arrayIndex (command 1), you display the whole array. If the command has an arrayIndex (command 2), only the array element at the index is to be shown.

Comment: `int arrayIndex = -1; std::string arrayName = "";  in >> arrayName >> arrayIndex;  if (arrayIndex != -1) { ..... }` Initialize your variables OR do it with two reads:  `if (in >> arrayName && in >> arrayIndex) {.....}`. It's still ONE stream just reading twice.